# How to minimize and resize PNG images with transparency in php

Tags: php, png, transparency, gd

I have **512 * 512 big size** PNG images with transparency.

How to create 256 * 256 PNG images with smaller file size, which also support transparency and maintaining quality.

EDIT: I'm using this code but the output image is cropped and not supporting transparency.

```
   $image = imagecreatefrompng("C:\Users\HP\htdocs\icon_hd.png");  // 512 * 512
    $bg = imagecreatetruecolor(256, 256);
    imagefill($bg, 0, 0, 0);
    imagealphablending($bg, TRUE);
    imagecopy($bg, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, imagesx($image), imagesy($image));
    imagedestroy($image);
    $quality = 100;
    imagepng($bg, "C:\Users\HP\out_icon.png", 9);
    imagedestroy($bg);
```

Comment: Have you tried Imagick::thumbnailImage ?

Comment: By reading the relevant documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.resizeimage.php

Comment: have you attempted anything or done any research on your own? The imagick is probably your best route if you haven't yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [ImageMagick](https://pecl.php.net/package/imagick) :

Simple example:

```
$inFile = "big_img.png";
$outFile = "small_img.png";
$image = new Imagick($inFile);
$image->thumbnailImage(256, 256);
$image->writeImage($outFile);
```

[More info](http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php)

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
$im = new Imagick();
$im->readImage('myimage.gif');  
$im->resizeImage(256,256,Imagick::FILTER_LANCZOS,1);
$im->setImageBackgroundColor('white');
$im->setImageAlphaChannel(Imagick::ALPHACHANNEL_REMOVE);
$im->mergeImageLayers(Imagick::LAYERMETHOD_FLATTEN);
$im->writeImage('mythumb.gif');
$im->clear();
$im->destroy();
```